# Drupal WebForm Conditionals

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

I need to build a webform where one of the questions asks the user to pick a date from a list of 5 dates. Each of the 5 dates only allows 10 attendees. How can I track the number of people that have registered for each date and limit the number of attendees? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for some custom solution. I.e. create some content type with 5 integer fields where you will keep count of attendees per day.

Then hook that webform (hook_form_alter()) and add another submission handler function, like described here:

[Drupal 7 Webform submit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174165/drupal-7-webform-submit-hook)

In that function (submit handler) read the form values increase counter if it has free space or shoot some message that no more places remained.